# Jquery use variable on click

Tags: jquery, click

i cant make this work,any ideas ? 
why the variable can not be happening with onclick?

html:

```
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail col-xs-6 col-md-3" >
                      <img src="img/PDF-icon.png" alt="..." >

                        <form action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type="file" accept=".pdf"  />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>                         
                    </a>
```

jQuery

```
  $(function()
{       
        $(".thumbnail").on('click','img',function()
        {   
            var x = $(this).find('input');
                $(x).click();           
            });   
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line:

```
var x = $(this).find('input');
```

`$(this)` refers to the `<img>` element. Since the `<input>` element is not a descendent of the `<img>` element, the call to `$(this).find('input')` is not finding the `<input>` element.

Try:

```
var x = $(this).next().find('input');
```